# Menubar based on links. Doesn't work background changing on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Menubar is based on a list of links. It's needed change background color on clicked item and leave it. In my case a color changes for a short time and gets back to CSS background.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".menu a").bind("click", function() {
    $(".menu a").removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
}

.menu li a {
  border: solid 2px white;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #a0a0a0;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.menu a.clicked {
  background: #b34a4a;
}

.menu {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
}

.menu li a {
  border: solid 2px white;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #a0a0a0;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.menu a.clicked {
  background: #b34a4a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="">ITEM 1</a>
      <a href="">ITEM 2</a>
      <a href="">ITEM 3</a>
      <a href="">ITEM 4</a>
      <a href="">EXIT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Added link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dae3sbdk/).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you're missing is the href attribute on menu elements. When you click on them if you don't set them at least to "#" the page will reload, and so they won't have the class "clicked"

Second thing I wrote a different js for you

```
 $(function(){ $(".menu a").click(function() {
   $(".menu a").removeClass("clicked"); 
   $(this).addClass("clicked");
   });
 })
```

Comment: Daniele thanks for the answer. So if i set # in reference, link won't work.
It was an example. In real menubar i've got href with php scripts.
like 
href="script1.php" 
and each script begins with  header mentioned above.
After each click php  script runs and reload the menubar. 
So  is it wrong way to change background on clicked item ?

Comment: Yes it is. if you want to set an active class ( "clicked" class) you should set it after the new page has loaded. There are plenty of ways you can do that, client side or server side